# Append to a div with jQuery and apply a css style based on a class

Tags: jquery, css, html, class, append

I want to append data received from the server to a div on my html page.  I can do that with

```
$('#divImAddingTo').append(infoBeingAppended);
```

I want to apply a css based style to that data being appended.  That I'm not sure how to accomplish.

I tried

```
$('#divImAddingTo').append(infoBeingAppended).toggleClass = 'className';
```

This isn't working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Comment: hey man please lemme know if my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15054589/766570) worked out for you.. if it did.. marking it as correct won't hurt :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('#divImAddingTo').append($('<div class=classname>'));
```

then

```
$('#divImAddingTo div').html(contentToAdd);
```

notice the difference between `.append()` and `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
$('#divImAddingTo').append($(infoBeingAppended).toggleClass('className'));
```

Comment: Ops, you're right. Just got my head ahead the 'apply a css based style' and thought in add :P. I edited my example to toggle the class instead.